# Find list item with class and get its list position in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="pageItem">1</li>
    <li class="pageItem">2</li>
    <li class="pageItem current">3</li>
    <li class="pageItem">4</li>
    <li class="pageItem">5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to calculate the list item position of .current. In this case it would be 3.

Just to make things clear: I don't want the X & Y position of the element. Just what number in the line it has.

Thanks!

Comment: Try document.getElementsByClassName('pageItem current')

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not compatible cross browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('li.pageItem').index($('li.current')[0]);
```

will return 2, just add +1 if you want the index starting from 1.

Comment: This is going to be very slow as elements matching two selectors will have to be found.

Comment: I had to login to say thank you for this one, it worked perfectly for what I was trying to do. Was trying to control tabs through inputs and for the life of me could not figure out how to select the next input I needed. I have several fields disabled so I wanted tab to carry to the next enabled one. This and a switched statement worked. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("li.current").prevAll("li").size()
```

// edit: actually, David's answer is better, since it shows more directly what we're after. The only thing, [0] is not needed, according to http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index, "if a jQuery object is passed, only the first element is checked.", that is, simply use

```
 position = $("li").index($(".current"))
```

Comment: You should use `length` instead of `size()` as it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li.pageItem').each(function(i) {
 if($(this).hasClass('current')) //i is your index
});
```

**Edit:**
`index()` is probably a better way to do it (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

`$('li.current').prevAll().length` will give you the position of selected item in the list. Notice that this value will be zero-based so if you want this to be one-based add +1 to this value.

Comment: lenght returns the length of the jQuery array (matches), not position. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index

Comment: I know what it does. You should check out what `prev()` returns. It will give you all preceding li elements and their count is what he is looking.

Comment: you mean prevAll() I assume :)